# Mutual Relationships with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following episode 163 of railscasts and it enables user to signify another user is there friend, but that's more or less it.

I would like to have a helper that finds if a user is their friend.

Get a list of users who are friends of each other.

List of users that have been sent requests that aren't mutual.

```
@friends_out = Friendship.where(:user_id=>current_user.id) #users "i" want to be friends with
@friends_in = Friendship.where(:friend_id=>current_user.id) #users who want to be friend with "me"
# users who haven't added "my" id to Friendship and vice versa
# user who are my friend and i'm their friends.
```

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post the code that doesn't work, if you have.

Comment: I'm not sure how to start, can I retrieve the friendships where user_id == current_user or friend_id == current and both and the access the friend or user from the friendship model?

Comment: in the console this works as expected :) f=Friendship.where(:user_id=>2).first.friend

Comment: this means i can get incoming friends and outgoing, but the subselect to see if they have added me as friends too is more complicated.

Comment: i've added my code to the question

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def friends_with?(user)
    self.friendships.where(:friend_id => user.id).any?
  end

  def friends_with_me?(user)
    user.friendships.where(:friend_id => self.id).any?
  end

  def mutual_friends?(user)
    friends_with?(user) && friends_with_me?(user)
  end
end
```

Then you could do something like:

```
current_user.friends_with?(other_user)
```

Comment: does friends_with_me? return all the friends of a user?

i understand the line at the end, and that's to check friendship between two users.

but how would I return a friends list?

Comment: Every time you need to find mutual friends, this code sends a lot of sql queries which is not a good thing instead it would be better if you can do these calculations once and save the mutual friends in another table so that its accessible easily. You could also run a job that would update this mutual friends whenever the user makes a connection